# Removing part of a string in column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove part of a string. But can't do it properly. String is like this: `4,290TL〜9,490TL` So trying to remove after this 〜

I tried

```
UPDATE SET price = SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '〜')
```

But not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SUBSTRiNG_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) requires 3 parameters, the last one being the delimiter `count`. In this case you need to supply a `count` of 1, indicating that you want everything to the left of the *first* occurrence of the delimiter `〜`. Additionally, you need to specify your table name in the query. Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET price = SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '〜', 1)
```

Comment: oh, part of it, worked but,  the rows are like this: 18,990万円(1戸)～28,790万円(1戸) not worked?

Comment: @Wowme add better examples into your question AND include the **expected result**

Comment: @Wowme the reason it doesn't work for your other data is that the two `~` characters are not the same character. If you look at [this link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54c89d9696b6e155cad809de09a9d936) you will see they are different. So you will need to run two updates, one for each different `~` character.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE SET price = SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, '〜', 1)

Comment: How does this add anything to the answer I posted 5 minutes earlier?

Comment: @Nick I tested in phpmyadmin, it took a little time and your answer is sooner

Comment: Well actually you couldn't have done that because your answer is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the the strings you have shared with this question or comments uses DIFFERENT wavy line ("tilde") characters

```
# the tilde character used here is DIFFERENT to the next example
select substring_index('4,290TL〜9,490TL','〜',1) 
;
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|    |      substring_index('4,290TL〜9,490TL','〜',1)      |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 4,290TL                                              |

# the tilde character is different to the one above
select substring_index('18,990万円(1戸)～28,790万円(1戸)','～',1) 
;
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|    | substring_index('18,990万円(1戸)～28,790万円(1戸)','～',1) |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 18,990万円(1戸)                                           |
```

You will need to be CERTAIN the the tilde you use as delimiter is the one you use in `substring_index()` otherwise that function will just return the whole string.

Comment: @NIck , yes I noticed after I had saved the above. You didn't note the consequence if an incorrect delimiter is used, and the proof you have offered is an external link. Difficult to deal with these things in a single comment imho

Comment: Given that the characters *look* identical I couldn't think of any way of demonstrating that the two characters were different other than showing it on a dbfiddle. As you say, a bit hard for a comment. Anyway good to have it noted in your answer too.